# Is it normal for a professional hardwood refinishing to not have removed black stains? (pet/iron oxide)

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing, stain

I recently had the hardwoods in my new (old) house professionally refinished. Besides the decades-old finish having been worn down completely, there were also black iron oxide stains throughout. After the whole house was sanded down, wood stained, and then 3 coats of poly, there are still visible black spots left. Is that a normal side effect of 67 year old floors or did the pro do a shoddy job?

Comment: If those stains go into the wood significantly deep then removing them reduces the thickness of the material to the point where it may need to be replaced... If they were ony surface stains then they would have been removed. Perhaps your contractor did the best possible with what you have...